# How to flash CyanogenMod with external SD card?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery

I messed up with the OS and now my phone can only boot to Clockworkmod and download mode.

How to flash the phone since Clockworkmod "install from zip" option can't read the external SD card?

<sup>My device is a Samsung Galaxy S.</sup>

Comment: Some device can be flashed by booting through Goldcard. Read many questions that are related and find with Google how you can prepare a GoldCard for your device.

Comment: What's your device model? Gold Card only applies to some very specific device from HTC, other manufacturers have their own ways.

Comment: 'adb shell mount -t tmpfs none /sdcard' then 'adb push update.zip /sdcard/'. After that you can install the update regularly (Maybe you need to enable adb first in the settings. This procedure creates a temporary tmpfs filesystem at /sdcard. You use it to just-in-time upload your update to it via adb, CWM won't notice that it's not the regular sdcard which is mounted and will be fine)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Summing up from the comments:</sup>

There are multiple possibilities. While not all of them might work, you still might give them a try:

1. [Narayanan writes](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27003/#comment-33196): Some device can be flashed by booting through Goldcard. Read many questions that are related and find with Google how you can prepare a GoldCard for your device.
   According to [Lie Ryan](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27003/#comment-33199), this will not be feasible for you, as it only applies to some HTC devices.
2. Recommendation [from ce4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27003/#comment-33206): `adb shell mount -t tmpfs none /sdcard` then `adb push update.zip /sdcard/`. After that you can install the update regularly (Maybe you need to enable adb first in the settings. This procedure creates a temporary tmpfs filesystem at `/sdcard`. You use it to just-in-time upload your update to it via adb, CWM won't notice that it's not the regular sdcard which is mounted and will be fine)
   This should work fine for you, provided you have *USB debugging* active or are at least able to activate it.